# Form validated but no email send

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

have some problems with my form which is being validated correctly, but when clicking submit button no email is going out. Mail fucntion is enabled on server as i checked raw mail sending. What can be wrong here? See my code below

HTML and JS:

```
....

  <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="bootstrap-assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Style -->
    <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/Lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/Icons/et-line-font/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/animate.css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Icons Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
            console.log("rrrr");
    } else {
        console.log("fff");
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function submitForm() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){

            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function formSuccess() {
    $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
});


</script>
```

contact form:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię, nazwisko" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn-block">Wyślij wiadomość</button>
<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

procrss.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "george@hgtg.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message, $email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked, if the post data reaches your php script? Are there any error messages, log data available?

Comment: Surely only typo -> url: "process.php" vs. procrss.php

Comment: Obviously there are several issues there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function isn't what you seem to think it is, it's just DOM ready handler that you have given a name to, and you should see an error in the console telling you that `submitForm()` is not defined.

Change it to just

```
function submitForm() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    ... etc
}
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function submitForm() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
   ....
```

---

EDIT: open the console (F12), and add some logs to see what's happening

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function(event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            console.log("rrrr");
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden");
});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function(text) {
            console.log(text); // should be "invalid" or "success"
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log('epic fail');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: changed but not helped

Comment: At least now the function is callable, as noted by jakub_jo below you also have an issue with the `From:` header in the `mail()` method, I'm not sure wether or not that would make the `mail()` method fail, in which case you'd get back `invalid`.

Comment: done both solutions and still mails is not comming in

Comment: Well, add a log in the ajax function to see if runs at all, I'll edit

Comment: see some error : SCRIPT1009: Expected '}'  in this lines:  data: $(this).serialize();

Comment: i got some strange message SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'validator'  on line  $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function(event) {

Comment: There is nothing called `validator()` in jQuery, which plugin are you using

Comment: also get some info: HTTP404: Not found - server could not find the item in accordance with the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET — http://mywebsite.com.pl/js/jquery.js

Comment: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/  this is validator but probably i attached it incorrectly

Comment: ^ and by that, he means just do `$("#contactForm").on("submit", ... etc` and remove the `validator.js` script, and see if the email is sent without the validator. The 404 error seems to be jquery.js, but you don't have anything like that in the posted code, there jQuery is correctly fecthed from a CDN ?

Comment: now its working without this validator... BUT how to reset all fields after message send and delete information "Message submitted" lets say after couple seconds would it be hard to implement?

Comment: and also message: "Message Submitted!" always appears even on page load. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The fourth argument of [**mail**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) should be additional headers, not just the sender's email address. So you've to rewrite your function:

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message, $headers);
```

But I'd suggest you add the sender's email to the message body. Since the suggested solution is vulnerable due to missing checks on the sender's email address.

```
$message .= "\n\n" . 'From: '. $email;
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message);
```

Comment: Checkout the typo mentioned by Sascha Kluth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529441/form-validated-but-no-email-send/35529493?noredirect=1#comment58748545_35529441

Answer (score 0):

Hiding your "Message submitted" message and clearing the inputs after a specified time is straightforward.

You would do this with a call to [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Something like this:

```
setTimeout( function() { myCleanupFunction(); }, 5000 );
```

That will call `myCleanupFunction()` after a 5 second wait.

Documentation on [how to use setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

or what it looks like in the original code:

```
formSuccess() {
    $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    setTimeout( function() { myCleanupFunction(); }, 5000 );
}
```

Comment: How to deploy your function into my example? Could you be so kind and show? I think also the problem is when you load my page this message is appearing...

Comment: Add that setTimeout call in your formSuccess function. I'll edit my answer to show.

Comment: seems not working - problem is "Message submitted" is appearing even before send form when you access my page its already there... think somwhere within my JS function is mistake, can you take a look?

Comment: @johndoe Your "Message submitted" is appearing at page load, because your `formSuccess()` function is being run by `$(document).ready()`. Not what you want. I'll simplify your javascript and post it in another answer, along with a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Several of your javascript functions are being called at page load time, which is not what you are intending.

Only put functions in a `$(document).ready()` statement when you want those functions to run at page load time.

Here's a working version of your javascript, and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/mbx6sr3g/1/) that replaces the `$.ajax` function with a test function called `testAjax`. All `testAjax` does is call your `success` function. (replace `ajaxTest` with `$.ajax` in production). You'll see that the jsfiddle behaves as you want.

```
function formSuccess() {
    $("#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    document.getElementById('msgSubmit').innerHTML = 'Message submitted!';
    setTimeout( function () {
        $("#msgSubmit" ).addClass( "hidden" );
        }, 5000
    );
}

// test version of ajax, replace with real "$.ajax()" in production
function ajaxTest( ajaxData ) {
    // just a test, so call the success callback
    ajaxData.success( 'success' );
}

function submitForm() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    // replace 'ajaxText' with '$.ajax' in production
    ajaxTest({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function (event) {
            // prevent default form submit
            event.preventDefault();
            // call our own submit
            submitForm();
        }
    );
});
```